Why does my gsheet select only work when it is specified as an embedded string in the query function, but not when referenced as value in a cell?
Documentation says that the select parameter of the query function can either be a quoted string or a cell reference containing the string.  However, I get different results when the same select string is used in each scenario.
The outcome I am trying to achieve is to have a single place to update the select statement.  I use the this query (and several similar) in a lot of places across a large workbook and want to have one place to make changes to the query if the geometry of the data table changes.
Referenced gsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vwZYlc4vPwP7R7m34oWQEPREeoxWWxctx_Y5JeI4zQU/edit?usp=sharing
Data:



A
B
C




John
Chair 1
Chair 3


Bill
Chair 2
Chair 4


Sue
Chair 5
Chair 6



The query function uses offsets to determine the value of the cell above it for the where clause in order to lookup the name of the person:



A




Chair 2


Query



First I created the following gsheet query function in cell E8 of the gsheet which worked as expected and returned a value of Bill.
=query(A6:C8,"Select A where B='"&OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),-1,0)&"' or C='"&OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),-1,0)&"' Limit 1",0)

Next, I took the select portion of the query and placed it in cell A14, and then referenced it in the query formula shown in cell E12, which resulted in N/A (no value returned):
=query(A6:C8,A14,0)
Value in A14:  Select A where B='"&OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),-1,0)&"' or C='"&OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),-1,0)&"' Limit 1
I expected the results to be the same in both scenarios.

Your goal is to get the offset from cell E12, so if you want to put the query statement in another cell, you need to use row(E12) instead of row() there.

The query() doesn't work because the query statement is invalid. You need to use a formula in cell A14 that gets a valid query statement, like this:
="select A where B = '" & offset(indirect(address(row(E12), column(E12))), -1, 0) & "' or C = '" & offset(indirect(address(row(E12), column(E12))), -1, 0) & "' limit 1"

...or, more succinctly:
=let( 
  cellRef, offset(indirect(address(row(E12), column(E12))), -1, 0), 
  "select A where B = '" & cellRef & "' or C = '" & cellRef & "' limit 1" 
)

...or, more simply, by using filter():
=filter(A6:A8, (B6:B8 = E7) + (C6:C8 = E7))


to make changes if the geometery of the data table changes

Cell and range references in formulas adjust automatically when you Insert > Columns, Insert > Rows, Edit > Delete > Columns and Edit > Delete > Rows.
See absolute and relative references.


Here's one approach you may test out:

Create a named function (Menu Options : Data > Named Function) using your existing statement string & then call that directly for iteration (as in screenshot)

formula defintion:
="Select A where B='"&OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),-1,0)&"' or C='"&OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),-1,0)&"' Limit 1"

Formula:
=query(A6:C8, Σ())


